# "App not installed" error when updating an app on Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

My Android app update gives the error message "App not installed" on Marshmallow while it works fine in a previous version.
I am using a signed APK  to update both the older app & the new app.

I am getting this error in the log when I update the app on Android One device(marshmallow)

```
02-03 11:24:56.025 138-151/? E/Vold: Error creating imagefile (Permission denied)
02-03 11:24:56.025 138-151/? E/Vold: ASEC image file creation failed (Permission denied)
02-03 11:24:56.025 138-151/? W/Vold: Returning OperationFailed - no handler for errno 13
02-03 11:24:56.025 557-607/? D/VoldConnector: RCV <- {400 92 asec operation failed (Permission denied)}
02-03 11:24:56.026 21687-21699/? E/PackageHelper: Failed to create secure container smdl870766772.tmp
02-03 11:24:56.027 21687-21699/? W/DefContainer: Failed to copy package at /storage/emulated/0/KAHMobile-release.apk
                                                 java.io.IOException: Failed to create container smdl870766772.tmp
                                                     at com.android.defcontainer.DefaultContainerService.copyPackageToContainerInner(DefaultContainerService.java:326)
                                                     at com.android.defcontainer.DefaultContainerService.-wrap1(DefaultContainerService.java)
                                                     at com.android.defcontainer.DefaultContainerService$1.copyPackageToContainer(DefaultContainerService.java:108)
                                                     at com.android.internal.app.IMediaContainerService$Stub.onTransact(IMediaContainerService.java:60)
                                                     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

installed on device & NEW APP APK have below possibility

1. both have different Signed Certificate
2. New App APK have small version code then installed

Comment: i have already checked both possibilities and update is working fine in lollipop & other versions except marshmellow.

Comment: @divyangpanchal: its show you installing screen? or not?

Comment: Thanks your post helped me

Comment: Thanks! The VersionCode was my Problem.
In My case i was using a flutter app with no build number. 
After disassembling the APK i saw that it had VersionCode "4", changing my App version to xxx.xxx.xxx+5 did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Your apps had to be uninstall and install back again.may be your app running again.but app are not running then please call marshmallow developer.

Comment: i can't uninstall older app. i need to give update to users from play store as i will use same older database with new app

Comment: @Jigs Ramani - What do you mean by "call marshmallow developer". Do you have any number of them ?